# Custom PAM modules and security considerations

Tags: security, authentication, pam

I am writing my own PAM module that will be part of an application that I am developing, but I'm not sure exactly where to put it. My module basically does network-level authentication (with other mojo of course) similar to LDAP.

There are a lot of config files in my `/etc/pam.d/` directory, and I know what most of the services do (except a couple, like atd, polkit, ppp). I assume that authentication with PAM stack goes something like this:

1. Runs stack based on service name (if a config file exists)
2. If not authenticated, fall back on common-*, where * is the module-type (auth, account, etc)
3. Return success or fail to calling application (and any other data of course)

**Am I correct in this assumption?**  **Do all platforms have common-auth, common-account, common-password, and common-session?**

If so, I was thinking about just putting it at the top of common-* as a `sufficient` module so that on failure the regular PAM stack would be left unaffected. This is particularly advantageous because I can programmatically do this on software install.

Am I missing any potential security vulnerabilities?

I couldn't find very good documentation on where to integrate custom PAM modules or security issues surrounding where to put modules.

Comment: The whole point of PAM is to decouple actual authentication procedures from applications, so to let sysadmins configure them separately.  If your application *depends* on your authentication module, this *might* be an indication that you are abusing PAM.

Comment: Well, my application is a daemon that syncs a user's account with the network if the logged-in user is a network user. I think as long as I don't allow communication between the daemon and the PAM module I should be ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call into Linux-PAM for some authentication procedure, there
is always one and only one stack that is run.

The stack definition is looked up in these places; the first
successful attempt determines which file is read:

1. the file in `/etc/pam.d` named after the application "service name" (e.g., `sshd` or `gdm`), or
2. the file `/etc/pam.d/other` if no service-specific file exists, or
3. the file `/etc/pam.conf` if directory `/etc/pam.d` does not exist.

See the documentation for function [pam_start](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/adg-interface-by-app-expected.html#adg-pam_start) for details.

The common-* files are a convention followed by many Linux
distributions but are not mandated by the PAM software itself.
They are usually included by other PAM files by means of `@include`
statements; for instance the `/etc/pam.d/other` file on Debian has the
following content:

```
# We fall back to the system default in /etc/pam.d/common-*
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session
```

The same `@include` statements may be used by service-specific file as
well, and -indeed- they are in the *default* configuration on Debian.
Note that this is a matter of configuration: a sysadmin is free to
change the file in `/etc/pam.d` not to include any common-* files at
all!

Therefore: if your PAM module is specific to your application, create
an application-specific service file and call the module from there.
Do *not* automatically add a module to other services' PAM file nor to
the fall-back `others` file, as this may break other applications
installed on the system.  Management of the PAM software stack is a
task for the system administrator, not for the application
developers.

Comment: This really cleared stuff up for me. Do some distributions use the common-* files as a backup for the service-specific config files? When I put my module in common-auth, it was run even when running sudo.

Comment: @tjameson I've updated the answer with more details on the common-* files

Comment: Ok, thanks!! Now I understand it all. I thought that perhaps my distribution had a custom fall-back procedure build in to their version of PAM or something. Thanks for clearing this up.